# How to use power law distribution package code in R

Tags: r, distributions

My data set is very simple, just one variable (continuous data).

When I try to get the Xmin and pars:

```
install.packages("poweRlaw")  
library("poweRlaw")  
m=file$Step.length.in.mm

est=estimate_xmin(m)  

m$setXmin(est)
```

The warning message is :

```
Error in m$setXmin : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What should I do using my data set to create power law distribution?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Asking for help to debug R code is [not on-topic here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As it stands the question does not seem suitable for Stack Overflow either, as you would need to add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/) 
for people to work with

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(poweRlaw)
x   <- rpldis(1e3, 1, 2.5)
m   <- displ$new(x)
est <- estimate_xmin(m)
m$setXmin(est)
```